# Video & Film Production?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is this Audio-Video Production site separate from the [Video & Film Production](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2797/video-and-film-production) proposal still under commitment phase? I got an e-mail about *this* site for having committed to Video & Film Production saying:

> We are launching your video proposal (today!) as part of a new site called Audio-Video Production.

Can someone clarify this as I feel Video & Film Production is significantly different from "audio/video production", specifically when it comes to non-technical aspects of film making, such as actors and such.

I suspect it will be separate since the V&FP Area 51 site is still ongoing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the link:

[**Video and Film Production [closed]**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2797/video-and-film-production)

The Video and Film Production proposal has been merged into this site as "Audio-Video Production."

Comment: Didn't realise it was made closed. I wonder if it's the right idea though? I would think film production has generally a lot of other stuff going on that would be polluted by technical questions, most of which seem to be about audio at the moment.

Comment: @Nick Bedford: It's a good fit. It has been suggested that, perhaps, we might try keeping a mostly technical focus on all aspects of video and audio production, while avoiding the film-school "storytelling" aspects of filmmaking. But that's a bridge to cross when the video crowd is in full swing on this site.

Comment: I'm happiest when there's little to no distinction between technical production and storytelling, and ideas bounce off each other freely. This may be a fundamental philosophy difference between the film/video and audio folks. I believe that things such as better interview techniques is perfectly relevant to both fields, even if traditionally the audio-only site didn't like to venture in that direction.  The forum I use as an example for production learning is rebelsguide.com/forum/index.php - there, Stu's got 7 main categories, all of which are fundamentally important.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Robert's comments on [this post](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/q/165/64) it looks like that proposal will be closed.